# Help with a homework question calculating interest

Tags: savings, interest, compound-interest

Question : 
Imagine that you deposit $6,000 a year, starting one year from today, for four years into a savings account paying 6% per annum. (That is one deposit of $6,000 per year.) How much money will you have immediately after you make your fourth and final deposit?

The answer I got was 25,274.18

The work was

6000/.06(1-(1+.06)^-5) = 25,274.18

I also tried this

6000/.06(1-(1+.06)^-4)= 20790.63

Both of them were incorrect. I really appreciate the help in advance. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second calculation would be correct if you were asked for the *present* value of the deposits. For the future value, you have 4 deposits, the first of which compounds for 3 years and the last for 0 years. Thus,
`FV = $6,000 * sum(i=0..3) 1.06^i = $6,000 * (1.06^4 - 1) / 0.06 = $26,247.70`

Comment: Thank you for the help, I am not sure where you get the sum(i=0..3), or where the i comes from . This part makes sense to me $6,000 * (1.06^4 - 1) / 0.06 = $26,247.70

Comment: See [here](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Calculus/Summation_notation). The i is a "dummy variable", and `sum(i=0..3) 1.06^i` is just a compact way of writing `1.06^0 + 1.06^1 + 1.06^2 + 1.06^3`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, that was very clear and thorough. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

When I'm stumped, I break problems down into their constituent parts, and since it's been 35 years since I took a finance course, that's what I'm doing here:

```
Year    Yearly:
  0     6000*1.06^4 =  7574.86
  1     6000*1.06^3 =  7146.10
  2     6000*1.06^2 =  6741.60
  3     6000*1.06^1 =  6360.00
  4     6000*1.06^0 =  6000.00
              Total = 33822.56
```

The correct answer I think depends on whether or not there's a final deposit.

Comment: The question is explicit that there *is* a final deposit, but that there is no initial deposit now ("starting one year from today"). You should remove the "Year 0" entry.

Comment: Thank you RonJohn for writing that out for me, and nanoman for correcting it.

Comment: @nanoman and OP: whether or not money is being deposited *now*,  it's still "*for four years*".  If the teacher meant "ending four years from now" then IMO it's confusingly written.